# Dexguard: avoid Class name and Logger obfuscation

Tags: android, logging, obfuscation, dexguard

How to avoid Class name and Logger obfuscation(Dexguard)

Dexguard: avoid Class name and Logger obfuscation from Android Release build Apk

Suggest me any one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep ProGuard and DexGuard from obfuscating a class name with a `-keep` option, e.g.

```
-keep class com.example.MyClass
```

This may indeed be useful if this is the name of a logging class that occurs in a configuration file. Alternatively, you can let ProGuard or DexGuard obfuscate the class name, but update the configuration file accordingly, e.g.:

```
-keep,allowobfuscation class com.example.MyLogger
-adaptresourcefilecontents res/raw/myloggingconfiguration.txt
```